# I can't find max and min

Tags: java, database, performance, data-structures

I want to create program read more than 10 numbers from the user and find the maximum number and minimum number then print all the numbers from the user.

This is my program, but I don't know how can I find the maximum number and minimum number:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ass3 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        int times , num1 ;
        int max , min;
        System.out.print("How many numbers you want to enter?\n*moer than five number");
        times=IOClass.getInt();
        if (times>5) {
           for(int i = 0;i<times;i++){
              System.out.println("please type the "+i+ "number");
              num1=IOClass.getInt();
           }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't store the numbers anywhere it's going to be hard to display them all.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize the `min` and `max` like this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

You can check whether the new number is smaller than `min` or bigger than `max`, and change them if needed:

```
int num = ...;
if (num < min) {
    min = num;
}
if (num > max) {
    max = num;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, hope it helps:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers you want to enter?\nThe number must be grater than 5");
        int times = in.nextInt();
        if (times > 5)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[times];
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Please type the " + i + " number:");
                int number = in.nextInt();
                numbers[i] = number;
                if(number < min)
                {
                    min = number;
                }
                if(number > max)
                {
                    max = number;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Max: " + max);
            System.out.println("Min: " + min);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: um, can you explain what everything do here ? i mean tell me what's the usefulness of each line. and how can find the total :(

Comment: Sure! so the `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)` is for user input in the console/terminal. Every time you want to get a number you use `in.nextInt()` where - in -  is the name of the Scanner. Because you want to now the min and the max you have to store all the numbers, so you have to create a Array `int[] numbers = new int[times]` where - times - is the size of the Array. Also you have to create some variables to now the MIN, MAX and TOTAL (assuming that the total is the sum of all the numbers). Then you have to now which is the min or max ( look at the IF STATEMENTS ).

Comment: So to now the total you just need to create a variable `int total = 0;` put it after `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` and then in each cycle of the loop (for) add the number to the `total: total += number` this line will be after `numbers[i] = number;`. If you need something else, please let me now! hope my brief explanation helps

Comment: what's the usefulness of this line ?     numbers[i] =number;

Comment: It is to store in the Array the numbers that the user gives. the name of the Array is "numbers" and the name of the number that the user typed is number. So each time the user types a number it will store in the Array numbers in the position i.